# StringBuilder, replace index with a variable

Tags: java, replace, stringbuilder

How do I replace a specific index of a index? I tried a `StringBuilder`, the problem is just that I want to replace the index with a variable:

```
  if (org == m2) {
    System.out.println(eingabe + " ist eine g\u00fcltige ISBN.");
  }
  else {

    if  (eingabe.length() ==13) {
        StringBuilder correct = new StringBuilder(eingabe);
        correct.setCharAt(13, m2);
        System.out.println(eingabe + " ist eine fehlerhafte ISBN. \nG\u00fcltig w\u00e4re " + correct);
    }
    else if (eingabe.length() ==18) {
        StringBuilder correct = new StringBuilder(eingabe);
        correct.setCharAt(18, m2);
        System.out.println(eingabe + " ist eine fehlerhafte ISBN. \nG\u00fcltig w\u00e4re " + correct);        
    }
  }
```

The error is following:

```
    isbn.java:36: error: method setCharAt in class AbstractStringBuilder cannot be applied to given types;
            correct.setCharAt(13, m2);
                   ^
  required: int,char
  found: int,int
  reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to char by method invocation conversion
isbn.java:41: error: method setCharAt in class AbstractStringBuilder cannot be applied to given types;
            correct.setCharAt(18, m2);
                   ^
  required: int,char
  found: int,int
  reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to char by method invocation conversion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
correct.setCharAt(13, (char)m2);
```

instead, since 2nd argument of `setCharAt()` should be of type `char`. The implicit conversion works only for promotions (conversions from narrower to wider types, e.g. from `char` - which is 2 bytes - to `int` - which is 4 bytes), but not the other way around. In the latter case you should do an explicit cast like this: `(typeName) variableName`.

Also, if your original `String` is of length 13, the index of last position will be 12, not 13, since positions are numbered from 0, not from 1. So your call to substitute last symbol should be:

```
correct.setCharAt(12, (char)m2);
```

in first case and analogously in the 2nd case.

Hope that helps!

Comment: now there are the following errors:

isbn.java:36: error: '.class' expected

isbn.java:36: error: ';' expected

isbn.java:36: error: illegal start of expression

isbn.java:36: error: ';' expected

isbn.java:41: error: '.class' expected

Comment: Your have wrong first argument (symbol position) in your `setCharAt()` call - see my edit.